# CSS moving top menu items to hamburger menu for smaller screen sizes without duplicating items

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have items in top navigation bar. As screen size get smaller, I want to move less important stuff to hamburger menu. I want to move less important items first, not just first from the right, so in determined order.

I did it using CSS media query.  by hiding top items and at the same time showing menu in hamburger menu. The problem is that I have to have everything twice, once in top and once in hamburger. It is also available here: https://jsfiddle.net/fqxndrhy/

```js
document.getElementById('hamburger').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('mobile_menu').classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

nav>section {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#mobile_menu {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 1cm;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

#mobile_menu.show {
  display: flex;
}

#desktop1 {
  flex: 1;
}

/* hiding certain items at smaller resolutions */

#mobile1,
#mobile2,
#mobile3,
#mobile4,
#mobile5,
#hamburger {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #desktop2 {
    display: none;
  }
  #mobile2,
  #hamburger {
    display: initial;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  #desktop5 {
    display: none;
  }
  #mobile5 {
    display: initial;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #desktop3,
  #desktop4 {
    display: none;
  }
  #mobile3,
  #mobile4 {
    display: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <section id="desktop1">desktop1</section>
  <section id="desktop2">desktop2</section>
  <section id="desktop3">desktop3</section>
  <section id="desktop4">desktop4</section>
  <section id="desktop5">desktop5</section>
  <button id="hamburger">☰</button>
</nav>

<div id="mobile_menu">
  <section id="mobile1">mobile1</section>
  <section id="mobile2">mobile2</section>
  <section id="mobile3">mobile3</section>
  <section id="mobile4">mobile4</section>
  <section id="mobile5">mobile5</section>
</div>

Open it in separate window and shrink browser width to hide top items. Items are hiding in random order and appearing in hamburger menu (desktop2 at 1000px width, desktop5 at 900px width, desktop3 and desktop4 at 800px width
```

Is it possible to avoid this duplicity? I've made some attempts but they were very convoluted, I'm looking for a simple, robust solution?

Comment: You can't avoid the duplicity if you want to acheive it with pure css. But you can use JS. With a listener on the window resize for example. Or you can also create the mobile part of the menu with javascript at the document ready listener by looping on the desktop menu, like this you will not have to duplicate the menu in your html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but it is a bit of trick using checkbox

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    nav {
        display: flex;
        position: sticky;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100vw;
    }

    #mobile_menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }

    #mobile_menu>* {
        flex: 1;
    }

    #hamburger {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }



    @media (max-width: 1000px) {
        #hamburger, label {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        #mobile_menu section {
            display: none;
        }

        #hamburger:checked ~ section {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1000px) {
        #hamburger, label{
            display: none;
        }

        #mobile_menu section {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div id="mobile_menu">
    <label for="hamburger">☰</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="hamburger" />
    <section id="mobile1">mobile1</section>
    <section id="mobile2">mobile2</section>
    <section id="mobile3">mobile3</section>
    <section id="mobile4">mobile4</section>
    <section id="mobile5">mobile5</section>
</div>
```

What i am doing here is showing hiding hamburger based on resolution and in mobile version i am showing/hiding items using combination of sibling and :checked selector

This is just CSS solution but generally JavaScript ones are more often and more flexible.